# Laravel guzzle parse error form json format

Tags: laravel, xmlhttprequest, guzzle

Here is my code

```
 $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.jewishgen.org/databases/wcf/wcfapifull.php?search=search&fname=a');

 $return_values = $res->getBody()->getContents();
```

I can get return data form this code:

```
 print_r($return_values);
```

But error.

```
 print_r($return_values->matches);
```

Here is error:[image]

Comment: please check my answer!

Comment: Its not working @MiladTeimouri

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert JSON manually (using `json_decode()` function, for example).

Use this sample code for working with Guzzle:

```
 use GuzzleHttp\Client;

 $client = new Client();
 $url = "https://www.jewishgen.org/databases/wcf/wcfapifull.php?search=search&fname=a";
 $response = $client->request('GET', $url);
 $jsonRes = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($response->getBody());
```